# DNS custom domain to subfolder

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a SaaS app where every user has a personal subdomain: `username.domain.com`. Every user has a personal blog at `username.domain.com/blog`.

Now I want to accept custom domains, e.g. `www.mycustomblog.com` would be an alias for `username.domain.com/blog`.

If someone browses to `www.mycustomblog.com/123`, the page `username.domain.com/blog/123` should be served.

However, I do **NOT** want a redirect. The user should still see `www.mycustomblog.com/123`in their address bar.

How can I achieve this behaviour? I have looked into Nginx reverse proxies, DNS CNAME records... but nothing seems to suit my needs. I can access both the custom domain DNS settings and all of the server's config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a rewrite. However your described logic doesn't work:

```
www.mycustomblog.com -> username.domain.com/blog
```

appears to be missing a piece of identifying information on the left side. Perhaps www.mycustomblog.com/username? After that, it's just a matter of writing out the match/map statements to change the request to match what you've got on the server.

Comment: Well, the domain name is in fact the identifying information. I have a mapping between domain names and usernames, but how could I use that for a rewrite?

Comment: Is "www.mycustomblog.com" the same for all of your inbound requests? What you need is something to identify in the source request to be able to map it to the destination.

Comment: "www.mycustomblog.com" is just user A's personal domain name. It uniquely identifies user A and should be rewritten to userA.domain.com/blog. Can I add this as a rewrite in Nginx?

Comment: Unless you can think of a good reason not to, that's how I would do it.